# Import XML document containing multiple tables

Tags: c#, ssis

I have XML documents which are uploaded by branches at evening. This uploading process is done on daily basis. Each XML file contains multiple tables which needs to inserted into SQL Server. Is there any solution either in SSIS or through C# program. I am new to this field.

Comment: Do XML files share the same schema, or its structure can vary?

Comment: Schema is same in all files. Only file name is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"D:/test.xml");

var connection = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
connection.Open();

// repeat for each table in data set
var adapterForTable1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table1", connection);
var builderForTable1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterForTable1);
adapterForTable1.Update(ds, "Table1");
```

Comment: @dmitrity there 100+ different tables in single XML file and every day I receive 130+ such files and every file name is different. Tables are same in every file.

Comment: Give an example of one such file

Answer (score 0):

If schema for XML document is fixed, you can use SSIS XML Source in DataFlow. It parces XML according to the schema and creates outputs based on it. So you can get data from tables and store it to DB with standard OLE DB Destination.
XML Source has configurable property to specify path to source XML file, so you can automate file processing with For Each File enumerator and in the loop - call DataFlow with XML Source.